# Is there a way to monitor which data items are queried in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a largish SQL Server database and we have Extended Events logging switched on.

One of the main tables has a column called `DataItem` which contains a relatively small (<100) number of values across the millions of records.

The client would like a report showing who has accessed each DataItem, when it was accessed, and with which technology.

Is there any SQL Server function or other software that can provide this?

Extended events gives the who, when and how but not the what.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `AUDIT` for this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16

[image]

Here you can add the name and location and how large the file can grow.
[image]

Enable it.
[image]

In the database you would like to audit, add the database audit.
[image]

[image]
Enter your Autit Action Type, in this case `SELECT`, but perhaps you would also like to see the `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` actions?

Don't forget to enable it:
[image]

After running some selects, you can see the audit information:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Peter, please forgive me if I misunderstand or if I've not explained correctly, but I believe this only shows that SELECT statements have been run.

Comment: When you see the last printscreen you can see the exact statement which has ran

Comment: Wait, thats what you said . But indeed, isnt that what you are looking for?

Comment: There are more columns than in the printscreen, also the application, IP is in the data.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, sorry for not being clearer. The client would like to see who queried "apples", for example. This could be expressed in a filter that is shown in the SQL statement but also could be included in another filter, say a date range. So it's more about auditing the data returned and not the query run.

Comment: Ah, as far as I know, this is the maximum we can achieve. But perhaps someone else has another idea ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I thought the same, but had to pose the question.